# $3$ equations - > $2$ unknowns and also trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I have a big problem with solving this one - I have $3$ equations, and need to find $2$ unknowns:

$$\cos(-55.82) = (0.6893\cos(-70) + 0.3381\sin(-70)) \cdot (\cos b\sin c_1 + \sin b\cos c_1) - (-0.6408(\cos b\cos c_1 - \sin b\sin c_1))$$

$$\cos b\cos c_1 - \sin b \sin c_1 = -\frac{(0.0533\cos(-70) + (-0.9057\sin(-70))) \cdot \cos f + 0.6423\sin f}{ \sin 67.33}$$

$$\cos b \sin c_1 + \sin b \cos c_1 = -\frac{-0.4206\cos f + 0.6423 \sin f}{\sin 67.33}$$

where $\cos =$ cosinus, $\sin =$ sinus.

As you can see, I need to find $b$, $c_1$ and $f$, but as far as I know $b$ and $c_1$ can be only solved in form of $b + c_1$. So the unknowns are: $b + c_1$ and $f$.

I need your help with finding the way to solve it, I'm more concerned about way of solving it than getting the answers.

update:
now I also know that: 
$$-80 <= b <= 135$$ 
$$-75 <= c1 <= 90$$
$$-175 <= f <= 175$$

Comment: So I edited, but confirm that I have edited it correctly, cause it was confusing..

Comment: There was one mistake, but it was on my part, there was "a" instead  of -70. Thank you very much for this editing and your effort.

Comment: Okay, and no problem..

Comment: Before starting any painful paper work, did you try solving it on a computer? Perhaps Wolfram can check if there is a solution.

Comment: Yea, I tried wolfram and 2-3 more sites but no solutions :/

Comment: What makes you think there's a solution?

Comment: Well, those equations are part of bigger work. I have everything solved step by step but in this case I have only answers and information which equations were used to get it. My job is to write an application for solving it, but I stumbled upon this issue.

Comment: Well either you have infinitely many solutions (which I understand is not what you want), or there is another restriction on the constant (ie a third equation) which you missed out.

Comment: Sorry for very late response, but I didn't have any more information until now. I found out that border values of b = +135, -80 and c1 = +90, -75 (in degrees). I hope it can help i getting the answer, beacuse I have no idea how to achieve that...